# logging with util-linux without systemd unit specified

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald

If I log with util-linux logger as below:

```
/bin/logger "hello world"
```

I can see through journalctl my log line:

```
journalctl --since "-1m"
Oct 08 09:12:17 myhomepc duda[11670]: hello world
```

however what is the default pseudo unit file used that I can filter with?

```
journalctl -u "duda" --since "-1m"
```

doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`journalctl -t duda --since "-1m"`*** should work.

`logger` interfaces to the syslog(3) system log module and makes entries in the system log with its SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER (--id), see man [logger(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html).

```
       --id[=id]
           Log the PID of the logger process with each line. When the
           optional argument id is specified, then it is used instead of
           the logger command’s PID. The use of --id=$$ (PPID) is
           recommended in scripts that send several messages.

           Note that the system logging infrastructure (for example
           systemd when listening on /dev/log) may follow local socket
           credentials to overwrite the PID specified in the message.
           logger(1) is able to set those socket credentials to the
           given id, but only if you have root permissions and a process
           with the specified PID exists, otherwise the socket
           credentials are not modified and the problem is silently
           ignored.
```

`journalctl` allows filtering of a specified SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER, per man [journalctl(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)

```
-t, --identifier=SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER|PATTERN
    Show messages for the specified syslog identifier SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER, or for any of the messages with a
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" matched by PATTERN.
```

Comment: The logger(1) manual page you linked didn’t mention `--id` or `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER`. [This one](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) mentioned `--id`, but it is the process id (an integer) instead of the syslog identifier (a string).

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the link and embedded the text for --id from logger(1)